# Can someone explain 3‐(propan‐2‐yl)cyclohex‐1‐ene forming a carbocation?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry

Can someone explain this one, especially the formation of the secondary carbocation (in the solution)?

> [image: Question]

Solution:

> [image: Solution]

After the electrophilic attack by $\ce{H+}$ on the π bond, I had expected the carbocation formation on the other side (the left end of the π bond) because of more hyperconjugation thus ruling out the chance of its rearrangement to the tertiary site. I've seen this happen in other questions too.

Comment: Carbocation: something with a positive charge on carbon. Carbonation: the thing that makes coke fizzy.

Comment: A more complete solution here relies on knowledge that the protonation is not productive, in the general sense that there is no capturing nucleophile. This means that the protonation is reversible. This should be clear based on the last step of losing a proton. That means it doesn't matter which end of the double bond is attacked--both are. But only the one that leads to the rearrangement matters here.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct that the $\alpha$-carbon would be protonated... and then deprotonated, and back and forth, until eventually, the $\beta$-carbon is protonated, the hydride shift proceeds, and the molecule is trapped in the product state. Since protonating the $\alpha$-carbon doesn't result in some other reaction, it doesn't really matter which secondary cation is more stable. I think the important thing here is recognizing where and when a hydride shift can occur.